# Controller loading different views (URL/Routing?)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

**The issue/brief intro**

What I'm currently in the process of making is a simple register/login-system (which will obviously expand into more later on). I've got a controller named `Users`, which features mainly two functions. One is `show_register()` and one is `send_register()`. This is paired with a model `User_Model`, a so called Factory `UserFactory` and currently (mainly for testing, these will later be combined) three views `register_success`,  `register_fail` and `show_register`. They are basically one view for saying that "Hey, congrats, you managed to register", one for saying "Oh noes, no register!" and one for showing the actual registration form.

Upon heading onto http://url.com/register, you are automatically shown the registration form itself (done through routing with `$route['register'] = 'users/show_register';`).

So, once you fill out the form in the `show_register`, the form action leads to the `send_register` function in the `Users`-controller. Input is checked, and if all is valid, it is sent to the `UsersFactory` for database input. If all is well, the controller receives "true" back as a result, and shows the corresponding view. *This is where our problem kicks in!*

If I manage to register, my URL is now: http://url.com/public/users/send_register. The public-folder is where I keep the files, and I've realized that needs to be removed from the URL through htaccess, which I'll find my way about how to do. The issue is that I don't wish my URL to be consisting of the users-controller and the send_register function of that. I wish it to remain as http://url.com/register/, but show a different view.

**What I've tried/looked into**

I've looked into routing first of all. I realize (hopefully I'm right about this, otherwise I need to learn how to read) that it won't work for the issue I've described. The main reason for that is because it takes whatever I specify and sends that to a specific class/function. In this case, what we're doing is already going to the right class/function, but the "wrong" URL is shown to the user. It's also difficult since I've got different methods inside of this controller, meaning that I can't statically map all actions to lead to a single function.

I've also looked into .htaccess, but I have not found a way to actually write it. For good measure, I'll have my .htaccess file printed here on the bottom in case it would help. All I've done is modify so that the index.php-file is removed from the URL.

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

If there are any other files you'd like me to show, I'll gladly do so. For now, all I can think of that could be relevant is the controller itself.

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller {

    public function show_register()
    {
        $this->load->view("show_register");
    }

    public function send_register()
    {
        // Populate the model with the information we got from the form.
        $data = array(
            'user_name' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'user_pass' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'user_email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'user_level' => 1
            );

        // Then pass that on to the User Factory, which will insert that into the database.
         $this->load->library("UserFactory");

         if($this->userfactory->registerUser($data))
         {
            $this->load->view("register_success");
         }
         else
         {
            $this->load->view("register_fail");
         }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for it taking so long for an answer to be given!

Why not just do an ajax call?

On your view where the form is:

```
<div id="message_box" class="hidden"></div>
<form  id="theForm" method="post" action="submitForm()"></form>

<script>
function submitForm() {
    $.post("<?= site_url('Users/send_register');?>", $("#theForm").serialize(), function(data) {
        success: $("#message_box").html(data).show();
        error: $("#message_box").html("<p>There was an error with your request</p>").show();
    });
}
</script>
```

There are of course a million different ways to do this. But I'm assuming those views are just message views, as in just short html success/failures (as you'd stated above). The advantage of ajax would be that the user would stay on the page, and you'd hide your url.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That'd definitely be one way to do it! I'm however a bit curious on how to otherwise do it. I'd like to avoid as much logic as possible in the view, and I have a feeling more advanced scenarios will show up as I go along where it won't be quite as simple as a success/error-message. Thank you though, I'm surely keeping this in consideration!

Comment: Alright, the other way to go would be to use the `redirect()`  method. You could make separate functions within your controller for `register_success()` and `register_fail()`, do a `redirect(Users/register_success)`, and the add those two to the routes like you had been explaining before

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why I didn't think of that. I dedcided to not use redirect though, but to instead simply have the register-function of that class handle multiple scenarios. Thanks for setting me back on track!